# Send Unicode String From C# To SQL Server 2008 DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to send some unicode strings (for example "ش") to my SQL DataBase stored procedure.
and my code is :

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Khane;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 



command.CommandText = s;
connection.Open();



SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
Common.CommonPersonSerchResult res = new Common.CommonPersonSerchResult();

res.ID = (int)reader.GetValue(0);
res.FirstName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
res.LastName = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
res.FatherName = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
res.NationalCode = (int)reader.GetValue(4);
res.ShenasnameCode = (int)reader.GetValue(5);
res.BirthDate = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
res.State = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
res.City = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
res.PostalCode = (int)reader.GetValue(10);
res.SportType = reader.GetValue(11).ToString();
res.SportStyle = reader.GetValue(12).ToString();
res.RegisterType = reader.GetValue(13).ToString();
res.Ghahremani = reader.GetValue(14).ToString();

SerchResult.Add(res);

}

connection.Close();
```

But I can't see any results but I know There is some rows can be show

this is my stored procedure:

```
USE [Khane]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[QuickSerch]    Script Date: 10/19/2011 18:31:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[QuickSerch] 
@item nvarchar(300)
AS
BEGIN    
select * from PersonsDataTbl 
where 
Name like '%@item%' or 
LastName like '%@item%' or
FatherName like '%@item%' or
NationalCode like '%@item%' or
ShenasnameCode like '%@item%' or
BirthDate like '%@item%' or
State like '%@item%' or
City like '%@item%' or
Address like '%@item%' or
PostalCode like '%@item%' or
SportType like '%@item%' or
SportStyle like '%@item%' or
RegisterType like '%@item%' or
Ghahremani like '%@item%' 
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stored procedure code should be:

```
LIKE '%' + @item + '%'
```

Otherwise you're looking for values that contain the literal string "@item".

Also, be aware that your code isn't likely to perform very well if you have a large number of rows in your table. Between the `OR` statements and the leading wildcards it won't be able to make use of any indexes. You might want to look into fulltext searching.

Comment: +1 And I guess the collation and accenting might need to be investigated too. I sincerely hope that there aren't many rows in the DB ... table scan city.

Comment: thanks but I don't know fulltext search and this Project doesn't needs it.Thanks agin.LIKE '%' + @item + '%' worked